# Elasticsearch-js has no existing documentation for count(...) - any examples/other docs?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch.js

I am using [elasticsearch js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) within my application and have successfully connected and queried data from elastic.

I am now trying to implement the `count()` method to return the number of documents in the index. Here is the simple code snippet:

```
elasticClient.count(/* params: CountParams */)
```

I replaced `params: CountParams` with `indexName` but I now receive an illegal argument exception saying that `... [/_count] contains unrecognized parameters ...`

I cannot find any documentation anywhere, whether on the api, stack overflow, or on other sites, regarding the count method.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide a working example or any links.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_count) help? Seems like that would be what you need, though it does not contain an actual example.

*edit*: how exactly does your call look? I'm not using the js client currently, but I assume you would have to add the parameter? Something like this maybe?

```
elasticClient.count({index: 'index-name'})
```

Comment: That works! I have to manipulate it a little bit more to actually return the count, since it returns a Promise, but that's easy enough. Thank you!